# Wordpress - Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying move my wordpress website from one host to another.

I downloaded the website backup and database backup from the previous host.

I uploaded the WP files to the newhost. I uploaded the database to the new host's database.

I updated wp-config.php.

Then whent I tried to access my website, I got the below error. I am very confused what goes wrong.

I got the below errors.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'wp_enqueue_scripts' not found or invalid function
>   name in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_print_styles' not found or invalid function
>   name in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_print_head_scripts' not found or invalid
>   function name in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496

Also I am not able to see the admin part also.

I tried to disable plugins via database to check whether any plugin conflicts with the site. But it went in vain.

My theme stylesheet is broken. Also some of the image urls showing the older host's url. I am really confused about what is wrong?

If you need any more info, kindly ask in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I walked into something similar.

My problem was that some of the files were completely missing from the Wordpress folder (I still don't know how that happened). But anyway, I got a fresh copy of wordpress, installed it, then moved my themes and reinstalled all plugins, and everything was back to normal.

Hopefully this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing the WP core fixed this problem for me.